# Appropriate use of affiliate links?

Tags: discussion

The use of affiliate links in [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/9590/45) has raised a flag. Specifically, the flag-raiser wrote:

> "I feel like affiliate links aren't appropriate here."

So, *are* they appropriate? If this isn't a good use of affiliate links, what would be? Would there ever be a fair & reasonable usage?

Comment: Personally, I feel that the answer actually _does_ use affiliate links in a fair & reasonable way. The author appears to be genuinely recommending those services, regardless of his own personal gain. In fact he makes a disclaimer about his affiliate links, and provides non-affiliate versions for those who'd prefer to bypass them.

Comment: There's also this thread: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2716/affiliate-links-amazon-and-others

Comment: Personally, I'm O.K. with responsible usage of it. Practically, I'd say it's easier to have a consistent policy of discouraging it.

Comment: Seems spammy to me, even if there are exceptions. And I think the main argument against it is, as @BradBell said, it’s far easier to have a policy that bans them than one that allows some but not others.